# How to remove special price from configurable parent product in magento2

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, special-price

We have migrated Magento 1 to Magento 2 after migration special price of configurable product parent is showing but we can't edit this special price in the backend.

[image]

Comment: https://bsscommerce.com/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-price-of-configurable-product-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

**Open the product in edit mode**.
    Scroll down to the **Price field**, and click **Advanced Pricing**. Then, enter the amount of the Special Price.

When complete, tap  **Done** . Then, tap **Save**.

Reference:[Magento](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-special.html)

Comment: when we edit parent configurable product price option is disabled  but in magento1 we can add price in parent configurable product and special price.

Answer (score 0):

In **Product Catalog** mark the product and then in **Actions** select **Update Attributes**.
In **Update Attributes** on the input Special Price, mark Change, let the value empty and then save. 
This in Magento ver. 2

Comment: how to do it by using sql query? m2EE